# Angular comments break my layout -- how to handle them?

Tags: html, angularjs, firefox

In Firefox Angular comments (which are automatically added to the webpage) break my layout. You can say it is Firefox fault (because comment should not alter anything -- after all it is a comment), but nevertheless the problem exists.

Here is the page created by Angular -- stripped to minimum, just to show the problem:

```
<table style="margin:auto">
  <tbody><tr><td>
    <ol>
    <li>
      <span style="padding-left:1em">
        <h3 style="display:inline">
          first
        </h3>
      </span>
    </li><li>
      <span style="padding-left:1em">
        <h3 style="display:inline">
          second
        </h3>
        <!-- ngRepeat: ... -->
      </span>
    </li><li>
      <span style="padding-left:1em">
        <h3 style="display:inline">
          third
        </h3>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

All `li` elements are created by Angular repeater, and for each there is a comment added. The middle comment however breaks the layout -- extra vertical space is created.

How to solve this problem? Is there a way to disable Angular comments?

Comment: What's the expected behaviour here? Should the `li`s be inline?

Comment: @nikjohn, expected layout is all lines are evenly spaced (vertically). The actual result is comment is treated as a half of the line, so in the middle I have bigger vertical space.

Comment: If this is indeed happening, then that is an issue with Firefox. One way to get around is to use a normalizing CSS library like Normalize. Edited my answer

Comment: Also, raise a bug with  Mozilla!

Comment: @nikjohn, of course it was my second step after asking this question :-) -- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1306559.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to disable Angular comments, but this will most likely break your Angular app, as Angular uses these comments to keep track of the DOM elements bound to directives.

If you want consistent performance of your web app across browsers, you can use a normalizing library like [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) and [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)

Comment: I don't want to change my elements per se (like replace table with divs). I want to stop Angular influencing my webpage with comments.